# binding spring modelAndView object value with angularjs ng model

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

what is the best way to bind modelObject with angularjs scope variable.
I have tried as follows

```
//controller
public ModelAndView getUsers(){
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
   mav.addObejct("username","somename");
   mav.setViewName("users");
  return mav;
}

//jsp
<input ng-init="name='${username}'">
 {{name}}
//output
somename
```

for the any other object

```
   //controller
public ModelAndView getUsers(){
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    List<String> username = new ArrayList();
    username.add("steve");
    username.add("mark");
    username.add("james");
   mav.addObejct("usernames",username);
   mav.setViewName("users");
  return mav;
}

//jsp
<input ng-init="name='${username}'">
 {{name}}
//output
[steve,james,mark]// the way looking like array but it is string format
```

thanks in adv.

Comment: can anyone have an idea on this?